# NSOpenPanel/NSSavePanel crashes in Swift 3

Tags: macos, swift3, macos-sierra, nsopenpanel, nssavepanel

In Swift 3/Xcode8.1/10.12.2 I am trying to use a NSOpenPanel to get a text file with the following code, written by DenBeke

```
@IBAction func browseFile(sender: AnyObject) {

  let dialog = NSOpenPanel();

  dialog.title                   = "Choose a .txt file";
  dialog.allowedFileTypes        = ["txt"];

  if (dialog.runModal() == NSModalResponseOK)
  {
     let result = dialog.url // Pathname of the file

     if (result != nil) {
        let path = result!.path
        print("browseFile path: \(path)")
        //filename_field.stringValue = path
     }
  } else {
     // User clicked on "Cancel"
     return
  }
}
```

The code opens a open dialog as expected and I can choose a file. Clicking the open button crashes the app. In the console I get:

> FI_TFloatingInputWindowController object 0x60800009c0c0 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug

When I run the code and open the dialog, in the console I get

> [default] [ERROR] Failed getting container for URL: file:///Users/ruediheimlicher/Documents/LoggerdataDir/Messungen/, error: Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=12 "App library not found: 'com.apple.Documents'" UserInfo={NSDescription=App library not found: 'com.apple.Documents'}

but this does not affect the app.

There are more examples for NSOpen or NSSave dialogs on the net with slightly different code, but with everyone I get the same result: Crash, and the exact same error on the console.

Is there a mistake in my code attempts, or even an example that works with Swift3/sierra?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give your app access to user selected files under `<Your Project> -> <Your Target> -> Capabilities -> App Sandbox -> File Access -> User Selected File`.

[image: User Selected File Permission]

Comment: I have no such setting in my project.

Comment: @heimi I adjusted my answer to the latest Xcode version.

Comment: I now get logs  with 'Faild to get owner UUID for url:' with  URL's pointing to a file on a computer I was last logged in as an administrator 6 years before.

Comment: heimi did you ever resolve this? I am getting this too. Could it be coming a preference file somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

> [default] [ERROR] Failed getting container for URL: file:///Users/ruediheimlicher/Documents/LoggerdataDir/Messungen/, error: Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=12 "App library not found: 'com.apple.Documents'" UserInfo={NSDescription=App library not found: 'com.apple.Documents'}

To remove this output you have to enable iCloud Drive in your Finder preferences.

- Open finder
- Open prefences
- Select third tab (Sidebar)
- Check iCloud Drive

Then rerun your application

Comment: iCloudPreferences are for a Code 2 error: `Code=2 "Logged out - iCloud Drive is not configured" UserInfo={NSDescription=Logged out - iCloud Drive is not configured}` but the above error is a Code 12 `App library not found` which iCloudPreferences doesn't resolve.